# Couldn't set refs/heads/master after moving from Git 1.9.5 to Git 2.9.0

Tags: git

I reinstalled my Windows on my machine: before I had Git 1.9.5, now I have Git 2.9.0. I am using TortoiseGit. After reinstallation:

- I made some changes to my local Git repo
- commited changes to local repo
- pulled from remote repo (which is on my machine's another drive)

Then I wanted to push the changes to remote repo but I got this error:

```
Counting objects: 8, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Writing objects: 100% (8/8), 151.54 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 8 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: Couldn't set refs/heads/master
remote: error:
To D:\rep\test.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (failed to update ref)
error: failed to push some refs to 'D:\rep\test.git'


git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1) (406 ms @ 7.7.2016 7:34:08)
```

What is wrong? What should I do?

.git/HEAD file exists in my local repo, so this is not a problem...

Comment: What ACL on `D:\rep\test.git\refs\heads\master`?

Comment: @PetSerAl: This is it! After Windows reinstallation my user didn't have enough permissions to change the file on external USB disk where remote repo was stored (it is NTFS). After correcting permissions I can push to remote repo. THANK YOU VERY MUCH! How I can accept your comment as correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@PetSerAl answered this question in a comment above: After Windows reinstallation my user didn't have enough permissions to change the file on external USB disk where remote repo was stored (it is NTFS). After correcting permissions I can push to remote repo...